# java.security.auth.login.config file in path with space

Tags: java, jaas

When I execute

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", ejbLoginConfig);
```

using `ejbLoginConfig = "../conf/weblogicdomain.conf"` and my client is in a path containing spaces, I get a ClassNotFoundException for my EJB call:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.app.MyFassade
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.RemoteBizIntfClassLoader.getClassBytes(RemoteBizIntfClassLoader.java:151)
...
```

If I move everything to a path without spaces, it works. Using an absolute path does not change anything.

Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 2):

The value needs to be contained in quotes (use escaped quotes):

```
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "\"" + ejbLoginConfig + "\"");
```